Qiskit - Run a noisy COBYLA optimizer of a circuit
I'm working on a quantum computing project using qiskit where I am trying to train an autoencoder on a noisy circuit. What follows is my approach so far, but I'm struggling with integrating the noise model into my circuit, then optimizing using a COBYLA optimizer with a SamplerQNN.
1. Define the noise in:
x_noise = XGate(label="x1") // "x1" so that "x" doesn't get noised
cx_noise = CXGate(label="cx1") // "cx1" so that "cx1" doesn't get noised
ccx_noise = CCXGate(label="ccx1") // "ccx1" so that "ccx1" doesn't get noised
noise_bit_flip = NoiseModel()

p_gate1 = 0.05
... # Add the noise into the noise model

2. Define the circuit:
n_qubits = 5
a = QuantumRegister(n_qubits,'a')
b = QuantumRegister(n_qubits, 'b')
out = QuantumRegister(n_qubits, "out")
c = QuantumRegister(1, "carry")

qc = QuantumCircuit(a, b, out, c)
... # create the 5 qubit full adder
... # this circuit uses the cx_noise, ccx_noise and x_noise gates created above

3. Now, create the autoencoder circuit:
num_latent = 3
num_trash = 3
num_add_qubits = circ.num_qubits - num_trash - num_latent

ae = auto_encoder_circuit(num_latent, num_trash)
qc = QuantumCircuit(num_latent + 2 * num_trash + 1 + num_add_qubits, 1)
qc.compose(circ,qubits=range(circ.num_qubits), inplace=True)
qc = qc.compose(ae, range(num_add_qubits, num_latent + 2 * num_trash + 1 + num_add_qubits))

5. Create the SamplerQNN to train the encoder:
qnn = SamplerQNN(
    circuit=qc,
    input_params=[],
    weight_params=ae.parameters,
    interpret=identity_interpret,
    output_shape=2,
)

6. Finally, creating the optimizer and cost function:
def cost_func_digits(params_values):
    probabilities = qnn.forward([], params_values)
    cost = np.sum(probabilities[:, 1])

    # plotting part
    clear_output(wait=True)
    objective_func_vals.append(cost)
    plt.title("Objective function value against iteration")
    plt.xlabel("Iteration")
    plt.ylabel("Objective function value")
    plt.plot(range(len(objective_func_vals)), objective_func_vals)
    plt.show()

    return cost

opt = COBYLA(maxiter=150)

objective_func_vals = []
# make the plot nicer
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (12, 6)

start = time.time()
opt_result = opt.minimize(fun=cost_func_digits, x0=initial_point)

Question
How can I effectively apply the defined noise model to circ and use the COBYLA optimizer to train my encoder? I haven't found any tutorials on how to integrate an optimizer with a noisy backend in Qiskit.

Try this link https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/verify there are a couple of sections there on simulating with noise models and building noise models

Hey @SteveWood, Thanks for the comment. I feel I have a pretty good understanding on running a simulation with noise. The thing I'm stuck on, is running an optimizer in a simulation (with noise). I couldn't figure out from the link you sent how to do that.

Here is a tutorial (VQE which uses an optimizer) that uses Aer Estimator and a noise model with Aer simulator https://qiskit-community.github.io/qiskit-algorithms/tutorials/03_vqe_simulation_with_noise.html as an example. In your case you would pass an Aer Sampler to SamplerQNN so that you can use Aer's noisy simulation capability (by default it uses the reference Sampler with an ideal outcome). Its not so much the optimizer more that its objective function is executing circuits in a noisy environment. Hopefully that helps.

@SteveWood gave the right answer, I was to use a Sampler from qiskit_aer.primitives. The backend options in Sampler allowed me to change the "noise_model" to be the noise model I created. Here is the code:
1. Create Noise model:
seed = 170
algorithm_globals.random_seed = seed

print()

devices = AerSimulator(device="GPU").available_devices()
print(devices)
methods = AerSimulator(device="GPU").available_methods()
print(methods)

method = "automatic"
device = "CPU"
if "GPU" in devices and "tensor_network" in methods:
    device = "GPU"

noisy_sampler = Sampler(
    backend_options={
        "method": method,
        "device": device,
        "noise_model": noise_bit_flip,
    },
    run_options={"seed": seed, "shots": 1024},
    transpile_options={"seed_transpiler": seed}
)

2. Running it:
opt = COBYLA(maxiter=500)

objective_func_vals = []
# make the plot nicer
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (12, 6)

start = time.time()
opt_result = opt.minimize(fun=cost_func_digits,x0=initial_point)
elapsed = time.time() - start
print(f"Fit in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds")

